# XHtml transformation - Copying nested children of the heaeder element

Tags: xml, xslt

An existing xml is modified to include the header section. I am trying to copy the nested children of the "Header" element "as it is" onto another xml file, but could not.

Xml with Header element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<QuestionText
  xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Styles;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Revisions;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns:n="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Notes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns:th="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Themes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  **<Header>
    <t:SubHeader SubHeaderAtt1="valA" SubHeaderAtt2="valB">
      <t:SubSubHeader SubSubHeaderAtt1="valX" SubSubHeaderAtt2="valY">
      </t:SubSubHeader>
    </t:SubHeader>
    <t:SubHeader SubHeaderAtt1="valC" SubHeaderAtt2="valD">
      <t:SubSubHeader SubSubHeaderAtt1="valM" SubSubHeaderAtt2="valN">
      </t:SubSubHeader>
    </t:SubHeader>
  </Header>**
  <Content>
    <p ListId="2" xmlns="">
      <span StyleName="ss">Item 1</span>
    </p>
    <p ListId="2" xmlns="">
      <span>Item 2</span>
    </p>
    <p ListId="2" xmlns="">
      <span>Item 3</span>
    </p>
    <p ListId="3" xmlns="" />
  </Content>
</QuestionText>
```

XSD to copy header :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Styles;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Revisions;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
    xmlns:n="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Notes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
    xmlns:th="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Themes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="QuestionText">
    <t:RadDocument>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="Header/node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <t:Section>
        <!-- Avoided for brevity  -->
      </t:Section>
    </t:RadDocument>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<t:RadDocument   xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Styles;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Revisions;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns:n="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Notes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns:th="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Themes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <t:SubHeader SubHeaderAtt1="valA" SubHeaderAtt2="valB">
    <t:SubSubHeader SubSubHeaderAtt1="valX" SubSubHeaderAtt2="valY">
    </t:SubSubHeader>
  </t:SubHeader>
  <t:SubHeader SubHeaderAtt1="valC" SubHeaderAtt2="valD">
    <t:SubSubHeader SubSubHeaderAtt1="valM" SubSubHeaderAtt2="valN">
    </t:SubSubHeader>
  </t:SubHeader>
  <t:Section>
    <!-- Avoided for brevity  -->
  </t:Section>
</t:RadDocument>
```

I would appreciate, if any one can explain what I am is missing or how to approach the problem. Any help will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"` on your input document's root element means that the `QuestionText` and `Header` elements are in this namespace.  Therefore

```
<xsl:template match="QuestionText">
```

won't match anything, and `Header/node()` won't select anything, because unprefixed element names in XPath 1.0 always mean "no namespace".

You need to map a prefix to this namespace and use that in the XPath expressions.  You probably also want to use `copy-of` rather than `value-of` to copy the header elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="xamlp msxsl"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:xamlp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Styles;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Revisions;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
    xmlns:n="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Notes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"
    xmlns:th="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Themes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="xamlp:QuestionText">
    <t:RadDocument>
      <xsl:copy-of select="xamlp:Header/node()"/>
      <t:Section>
        <!-- Avoided for brevity  -->
      </t:Section>
    </t:RadDocument>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a way to avoid using prefix for the element? I used xslt before, but never used prefix.

Comment: @teenboy you don't have to use a prefix for the element.  You're just defining a prefix _in the stylesheet_ for use in its XPath expressions and match patterns.  XPath operates on namespace-well-formed XML, and all it cares about is the local name and the namespace URI.  The prefix (or lack of prefix) used in the original document and the prefix used in the XPath expressions don't have to be the same, they just have to map to the same URI in their respective places.